# Add Quartz.net job without starting the scheduler

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, quartz.net

Is there any way of adding jobs to [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) jobstore without starting up a scheduler instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For creating a managing instance (a scheduler that is used just for job and trigger configuration, like web) you can change your thread pool to ZeroSizeThreadPool that allows you to start scheduler without the fear of it actually running any jobs.

You should always use the scheduler interface instead of direct database access.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a database based job store you could add it directly to the database. Although that's not the recommended way of doing it, it's certainly possible.

Comment: I have tried that, by using some of the data-access-classes in Quartz, but some of the parameters are not set. I think it is to much of a hack of i need to calculate internal values on my own.